# Excel VBA Copy matching information from one worksheet to another with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a macro in Excel working.

Right now I have a worksheet called "Forms" with 3 columns - the headings (in row 1) are A = Form Number, B = Form Name, C = Parts
I also have a worksheet called Ins, which has the same exact headings and is populated with the information already.

I'm trying to get it so that I can enter in the form numbers on "Forms" in column A and have the information from Ins automatically copy over for columns B and C. I have EntireRow in the code right now, but I would prefer it if I could have it specifically only copy to column A to C, but I can't think of how.

Here is the code I'm currently trying to use:

```
Private Sub Auto()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set wks1 = Sheets("Forms")
Set wks2 = Sheets("Ins")

lastline = wks1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastline

wks2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
wks2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, wks1.Cells(i, 1).Value
wks2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Copy wks1.Cells(i, 1)
wks2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: I understand that you want to enter `Form Name` in column `A` and have the `B` and `C` populate automatically?  *`I have EntireRow in the code right now, but I would prefer it if I could have it specifically only copy to column A to C, but I can't think of how.`* can you elaborate?

Comment: Is there only one instance of each form in column A of Worksheet ins? Why do you need to do this in VBA and a loop? Why not just use Vlookup or Index/Match?

Comment: Tim solved the EntireRow problem for me below... Now the problem I am having is just the headers are being copied.  I can't use Match because I need the values copied in for record keeping, the values in Ins change sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wks2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(,3).Copy wks1.Cells(i, 1)
```

EDIT: something like this would be better I think

```
Private Sub Auto()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet
Dim f As Range, frmNum
Dim lastLine As Long

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set wks1 = Sheets("Forms")
Set wks2 = Sheets("Ins")

lastLine = wks1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastLine
    frmNum = wks1.Cells(i, 4).Value
    If Len(frmNum) > 0 Then
        Set f = wks2.Columns(1).Find(frmNum, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 9).Copy wks1.Cells(i, 5)
        Else
            wks1.Cells(i, 5).Value = "??"
        End If
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just copy the headers over and over?

Comment: I did not read the question closely, but I assumed the OP knew what they wanted: if `EntireRow` worked for them but they's rather not copy the entire row but just the first 3 columns then my answer does just that...

Comment: The headers just copying over is one of the problems I am having.  This solved my EntireRow problem though!  Thank you!

Comment: @TimWilliams Do you know what to change to get the macro to copy the information?  Currently if you enter form numbers and run the macro just the headers copy and then sometimes info for one of the forms at the bottom.  Here is a link to the form itself: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By75DJok81joQnJESGNLOXhiXzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Here is more on what i mean in my comment, If you just want what you asked for it can be accomplished using formulas:

The formula would be:

```
B2 = =IF(A2<>"",VLOOKUP(A2,Ins!$A$1:$C$14,2,FALSE),"")
```

and

```
C2 = =IF(A2<>"",VLOOKUP(A2,Ins!$A$1:$C$14,3,FALSE),"")
```

If you Ins worksheet looks like this:

[image]

Then you Forms worksheet will look like this after the formulas are dragged down:

[image]

Comment: This would work except I need them to copy over, they can't be variable

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting this to work by adding a third workbook and entering the form numbers in column A there!

```
Private Sub Auto()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wks1 As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set wks1 = Sheets("Form Worksheet")
Set wks2 = Sheets("Instructions")
Set wks3 = Sheets("To Do")

lastline = wks1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastline

wks2.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
wks2.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, wks3.Cells(i, 1).Value
wks2.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize(, 10).Copy
wks1.Cells(i, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
wks2.Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter


Next i


End Sub
```

But I ended up using Tim's version.

Thanks guys!